# What is the meaning of "position is: 187"

Tags: position

I open 2 windows in PyCharmProject.
Project 3 is try and error
Project 4 store my real program

Under project 3, I wrote a simple python program
print "Hello world"

but the output show

postion is: 187

Process finished with exit code 0

After I run, I expect the Project 3 window show the output Hello world